# SQL select columns group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

If I have a table which is of the following format:

```
ID NAME NUM TIMESTAMP BOOL
1  A    5   09:50     TRUE 
1  B    6   13:01     TRUE
1  A    1   10:18     FALSE   
2  A    3   12:20     FALSE
1  A    1   05:30     TRUE
1  A    12  06:00     TRUE
```

How can I get the ID, NAME and NUM for each unique ID, NAME pair with the latest Timestamp and BOOL=TRUE.

So for the above table the output should be:

```
ID NAME NUM
1  A    5
1  B    6
```

I tried using Group By but I cannot seem to get around that either I need to put an aggregator function around num (max, min will not work when applied to this example) or specifying it in group by (which will end up matching on ID, NAME, and NUM combined). Both as far as I can think will break in some case.

PS: I am using SQL Developer (that is the SQL developed by Oracle I think, sorry I am a newbie at this)

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like this is often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: I am using SQLDeveloper, and probably should have specified that.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using at least SQL-Server 2005 you can use the [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT ID, NAME, NUM,
      RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID, NAME ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC)
   FROM Table
   WHERE BOOL='TRUE'
)
SELECT ID, NAME, NUM FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

Result:

```
ID     NAME   NUM    
1       A      5     
1       B      6
```

Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1dc9/10/0

Comment: Thanks for this, it works flawlessly, but can you explain what's happening as well?

Comment: @user1536435:  The [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) adds the [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) window function as column partitioned by the [`OVER-Clause`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx). `PARTITION BY` is similar to a `GROUP BY`. Read here for the differences: http://iggyfernandez.wordpress.com/2010/03/19/comparison-between-window-functions-and-the-group-by-clause/ The `ORDER BY` in the `OVER`-clause determines the number of the row in the set.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.* from table as t1 inner join
(
select NAME, NUM, max(TIMESTAMP) as TIMESTAMP from table
where BOOL='TRUE'
) as t2
on t1.name=t2.name and t1.num=t2.num and t1.timestamp=t2.timestamp
where t1.BOOL='TRUE'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.* 
from TABLE1 as t1 
left join
TABLE1 as t2 
on t1.name=t2.name and t1.TIMESTAMP>t2.TIMESTAMP
where t1.BOOL='TRUE' and t2.id is null
```

should do it for you.